# How to replace a string in mongodb using $eq and $cond

Tags: mongodb

I have a database containing people and their information (name, gender, etc...)
Example:

```
{
    "id": 31,
    "balance": "$1,137.95",
    "age": 24,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Burris Newton",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "XOGGLE",
    "email": "burrisnewton@xoggle.com",
}
```

I want to replace "male" by "H" and "female" by "F" for the gender in my database using $cond

I have written this but it doesn't work

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            age: 1,
            name: 1,
            gender: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        "gender": {$eq: ["$gender", "male"]},
                        then: "H",
                        else: "F"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You can find the correct syntax from [$cond document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#example), correct this `if: { $eq: ["$gender", "male"] }`

Comment: @turivishal that is what used that's why i don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: verify again both are different this is incorrect > `{ if: { "gender":{ $eq: ["$gender", "male"]}` and this is correct > `if: { $eq: ["$gender", "male"] }`

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using [piplined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), this is available for Mongo version 4.2+, if you're using a lesser version you will have to do this in code by iterating each document one by one.

Here is the code sample using this feature:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "gender": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$gender",
              "male"
            ]
          },
          "H",
          "F"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ed30jJCQQO)

*Note if documents can have missing gender field then you will have to address this otherwise they will get the `"F"` value.